# How to expand non-entity reference in xml file with Ant

Tags: java, ant, xml-parsing, xmltask

I have an XML file with the following content:

```
<root-tag>
  <entry name="name1" value="/usr/bin" />
  <entry name="full_path" value="${name2}" />
  <entry name="name2" value="${name1}/dpkg" />
</root-tag>
```

I want to read this file in Ant and put the attribute value of `value` in the `<entry>` node whose `name` value is "full_path" into a property with Ant.

I can easily do this, e.g. using `<xmltask>` with its `<copy>` element:

```
<copy path="root-tag/entry[@name='full_path']/@value" property="outputProperty" />
```

However, what I get is `${name2}`, which is meaningless to me. I need `${name2}` to be resolved into the `${name1}/dpkg` and then the `${name1}` part is resolved into `/usr/bin`, as a result, `/usr/bin/dpkg`.

And I must look for "full_path" because the other two names can't be predicted.

Since this is not entity reference, `<xmltask>` can't automatically expand it.

How should I achieve my goal in Ant build file?

Answer (score 0):

You can use anttask propertycopy for the same.
Refer link - http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/propertycopy.html